# How can I change a column's data type?

Tags: cassandra

I created a column with the type of text and I dropped it.
Then I wanted to create a column with the same name but with the type boolean. However, the system told me:

```
Cannot re-add previously dropped column 'isyoung' of type boolean, \
  incompatible with previous type text
```

I didn't find any relevant information on the Cassandra website.
I had already dropped the column, but I couldn't alter the table to add that column back.

I don't want to rebuild my whole table.
How can I change the column's type?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change a column's data type.

The ability to do that was removed in Cassandra 3.0.11 and 3.10 ([CASSANDRA-12443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12443)) because it causes a lot of issues including nodes unable to start, unable to replay commitlog mutations and other data corruption.

Recall that in Cassandra, SSTables are *immutable* -- they don't change or get updated once they've been written to disk. If changing column types was allowed, it would render data in the existing SSTables unreadable because the data no longer matches the schema.

Similarly, it would be impossible to restore the data from backups because the live schema would no longer match the schema in the backups.

Similarly if you attempt to run `ALTER TABLE ... TYPE`, the command will return an error similar to:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] \
  message="Altering column types is no longer supported"
```

Dropping then re-adding a column with the same name but with a different type also causes the same issues so it has also been disallowed a long time ago ([CASSANDRA-14843](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14843), [CASSANDRA-14948](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14948)). Cheers!